How to describe integers with the same prime factors?
Is there a term for the relationship between two integers that have the same prime factors?  For example, $6=(2)(3)$ and $12=(2)(2)(3)$.  Can one describe this with something along the lines of "$6$ and $12$ are <term>" or "$6$ is <term> to $12$"?
ETA: "Multiples" is indeed not what I'm after.  $6$ and $30$ do not have the relationship I'm describing, because $30$ has a prime factor of $5$ that it does not share with $6$.

I'm unfamiliar with any such term. You can get something related, greatest, square-free, common factor. It's like the gcd, only the prime factors are only raised to the first power.

Multiples is the first word that comes to mind, but I sense this is not what you are after.

I'd call them "factor brothers/sisters/sibs", but that's a term I just invented.

Something that's close to an answer: "$6$ and $12$ have the same radical".
The radical $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ of an integer $n$ is the product of its distinct prime factors; as a result, if two integers have the same radical, then they have the same prime factors, too. This notion comes up, for example, in the statement of the abc conjecture.

The support describes the prime factors if you consider integers as ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$.
